# Mail log file from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to send mail automatically from my app, with attachment of log file, If there was any Crash issue or catch error in my app.How to get device log file from objective C.

Thanks
Vadivelu

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737701/get-previous-run-crash-logs-on-iphone